# Modifying committed patch in git

Tags: git, patch

I applied a patch to my repo which accidentally contained trailing spaces.  When I do a "git rebase master", git complains about the trailing spaces.  How can I fix the patch to eliminate the trailing spaces?

I thought to reset the top of the branch to the patch which needs to be modified, fix the trailing spaces, then reapply the patch:

```
$ git reset --hard <commit-id>
< edit files>
$ git commit --amend
```

Is there a better way to do this?

How to I get the branch back to its previous state, with subsequent patches applied?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you did not yet publish (push) your commits, there is no problem in modifying those commits.

The main command for doing this is `git rebase -i`, which works best with a proper configured upstream.

It will show you all your local commits, which are not yet pushed to upstream. You can then decide to reorder them, squash multiple commits into a single one, change commit messages or change the content of the commit completely.

It seems you are after the last one. ;)

In this case git will reset you to that commit, allowing you to amend it and a following `git rebase --continue` will replay the remaining commits.

An alternative way might be to add a new commit fixing things, and use `git rebase -i` afterwards to combine this commit with the faulty one.